# What Do We Expect Likelihood Function to Be Used For?

Tags: image-processing, noise, estimation, statistics, maximum-likelihood-estimation

In my understanding, I let make a example.

For example,  you can see in the following picture.

Consequently, We want to find  ^sigma. and We have already known the observation data(which is random data such as C) and bin(0.3).

To know "the estimated standard deviation ^sigma", First of all,

1. Find Likelihood for each bins with observed data( for example, data of C).
2. Find Maximum Likelihood among previous Likelihood values(from 1).
3. the Maximum Likelihood is "the estimated standard deviation ^sigma".  Am I wrong?
   In other words, the Maximum Likelihood (^sigma) represent all bins's Likelihood values.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you start with a probabilistic model of your data (observations). That model includes a noise term which has some variance or standard deviation which can vary over time or can be fixed. Then you write up the joint pdf of the data, normally written something like this $p(\boldsymbol{x}|\theta)$, where $\theta$ is a vector that includes all the parameters in the model including the noise variance. Then in likelihood estimation the pdf is viewed as a function of $\theta$ (data is fixed). The parameter vector that maximizes this function is the most likely parameter vector in the sense that it maximizes the probability that the model has generated the data. What your plots seem to indicate is that the underlying estimator is biased which means that the expected estimate is not the true value.

The ML estimator is a function. It takes as input your data $\boldsymbol{x}$ and provides a value (the estimate) $\hat{\theta}$. Your data is random, it is governed by a pdf. Because you plug random data into your estimator your estimate will also be a random variable governed by some pdf. I think this is what is illustrated in those images. Those plots illustrate the pdf of the estimate. It is then of course interesting to know if the expected value (the mean) of the estimate then is equal to the true value.

Comment: Sir thanks for letting me but I have some query and I added update. If you can, would you please some simple example let me know?

Comment: I'm not familiar with image processing. Maybe you can read your references and then ask questions here whenever you read something that you don't understand. Step-by-step.

Comment: No my question is not about Imageprocessing. I just question about what do we expect from MLE? What does it mean when one model fits the data better than does it competitor model?

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between ML estimation and MAP estimation? By definition an ML estimator $\hat{\theta}$ maximizes $p(\boldsymbol{x}|\theta)$ or $\hat{\theta} = \underset{\theta}{\operatorname{argmax}} p(\boldsymbol{x}|\theta)$

Comment: Do you have different models? or are you taking about parameter estimation in a model? Please clarify

Comment: I'm talking abouy parameter estimation.

Comment: I have added a few lines very briefly explaining the plots as I understand them.

Comment: sorry I have add some query.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean by writing "it is governed by pdf" is that the random variable is associated with a pdf. The output of the estimator is an estimate of the standard deviation in your example.

Comment: Oh! I get it. Then I have some query. If we get a most probability from likelihood.(in my example), then can we tell the one most likelihood represent another all (which mean another all properties ignored by most likelihood)?

Comment: Can you try to rephrase what you're asking. I don't understand.

Comment: Sorry. If we get a biggest probability from each likelihood in my example, then can we tell the one biggest likelihood probability represent another all likelihood probability?(shortly, do the one biggest likelihood probability value represent all of them?)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "each likelihood". There is one likelihood function and the parameter that maximizes this function is the estimate.

Comment: once I have add and clear out my question.

Comment: If you can would you please let me know the my question about each likelihood ?

Comment: Sir I have a question about using the Likelihood function. As you said, there are just one MLE which is used. But Is that can be possible to well estimate by using MLE? That is ,How does accuracy by using MLE?

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand what your question is. I suggest you make a new question and then make an effect to be precise and clear. For instance your question "How does accuracy by using MLE?" does not make any sense to me.

Comment: @niaran I meant that as I know the estimation of pdf by MLE is can be possible about accuracy confidence problem. don't you? it's just estimate so we can not get exactly same true value of original noise STD.

Comment: @niaran briefly, can we say what above method which is to estimate ^sigma of ^sigmas by using MLE?